# Why does Google require "image" for breadcrumbs?

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, google-rich-snippets

Why does Google require an image (in the sample I see icon) for a breadcrumb?

See [Google breadcrumb document](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs#type_definitions).

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image is not required. It is a mistake in the documentation.
[John Mueller](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/763986878781530112?s=09) says it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am really wondering now.

If you take the example from the documentation, take out the image and pass it through the markup tool test.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/books",
      "name": "Books"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "item": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/books/authors",
      "name": "Authors"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "item": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/books/authors/annleckie",
      "name": "Ann Leckie"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 4,
    "item": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/books/authors/ancillaryjustice",
      "name": "Ancillary Justice"
    }
  }]
}
</script>
```

It comes with error saying the image is required.

Comment: Funny opening it in inconito mode I don't see this error 

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not really required to get a working rich snippet in search results.

I don't know why it is marked as required in the documentation.